# How to write a mysql query in cakephp to join 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, join

where i want to display my project lists but i've stored projects in one table, project catagories in other tables and Catagories in another table, FYI  i'm storing the proj_id of projects in project_catagories table and in project_catagories i'm storing cat_id which is the id of catagories. so i want to display, allprojects,all its catagories along with it.

Comment: You may want to check here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good read before you start development in  CakePHP
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html